How to annotate python function with different return type based on parameters?
There are some cases when a function will return different type based on the parameter input.
A simple example could be
from typing import Union

def func(is_str: bool) -> Union[str, int]:
    if is_str:
        return "string"
    else:
        return 42


a:int = func(is_str=False)

For pylint, it will raise a warning:
Type "str | int" is not assignable to declared type "int".

I wonder what is the best practice for circumstances like this.

What I tried
One suggested way is to rewrite the function with decorator @overload, but this scenario also happens for some package dependencies, when the function body is relative long (e.g. a function handling network request, and decide whether to return a json type(response.json()) or a string(response.text).)

Another way for this is
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def func(return_type:T = str) -> T:
    if return_type is str:
        return "string"
    else:
        return 42

That would also raise some warnings.
Type "Literal[string]" is not assignable to type "T@func"
Type "Literal[42]" is not assignable to type "T@func"

Is is possible to avoid the warning without modification the function?

Another approach for solving this would be:
from typing import Union

def func(is_str: bool) -> Union[str, int]:
    if is_str:
        return "string"
    else:
        return 42

a:Union[str, int] = func(is_str=False)

if isinstance(a, str):
    raise TypeError('parameter a should be an integer.')

So that variable a will be considered an integer for pylint in later code.
this practice is needed when the code is long, but for short code cases, it is just obvious, and write the checking can be tiring especially when calling the function multiple times.

The short answer is overloads, which work just fine for your example, so it's unclear how exactly you've tried to apply them or what the real problem you're trying to solve is.

Usually, it's better to just define two distinct functions, and select the correct one to call based on the would-be argument, rather than making a single function do different things based on its argument.
